# Replace multiple attribute values at once

Tags: xml, replace, expression, notepad++

I have a fairly large XML document with multiple attributes in it. All of the attributes currently have the value of "String," because it's a sample file without actual data. So the file looks something like this:

```
<Message>
 target="String"
 type="String"
 date="String"
 etc. etc.
>
```

Is there a way to replace every instance of "String" with the attribute name that appears just before the = ? So every attribute would look like this:

```
<Message>
 target="target"
 type="type"
 date="date"
 etc. etc.
>
```

Is this possible using a regular expression in Notepad++? Or using something else? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ use a regular expression replace. Set the **Find what** to be `\b(\w+)="String"` and the **Replace with** to be `\1="\1"`. You may want to adjust the capitalisation of the word `String` and the setting of the **Match case** tick box.

Explanation. The `\b` matches the boundary between what is a word and what is not. The `(\w+)` matches one or more word characters and saves them in a capture field. The `="String"` matches itself. In the replacement the `\1` inserts the saved capture field; it is inserted twice along with the other wanted characters.

If the above replaces too many items in the file then try searching for `^_(\w+)="String"$` and replacing with `_\1="\1";` note the `_` should be replaced by a single space in both strings, the change is made here to clearly show where spaces should be placed. The above explanation applies, but additionally the `^` at the very start of the **Find what** matches the beginning of the line and the `$` matches at the end of the line.